# Stop LINQ to SQL from executing select statements after insert

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL to update my database.  I'm inserting a lot of records, and when I call SubmitChanges(), LINQ to SQL executes an insert and a select statement for each object.  I don't really care to update my objects after they are inserted into the database.

Do you know I can prevent LINQ to SQL from issuing the select statements after the insert statements?  This should make my app much faster.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [ColumnAttribute.AutoSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.autosync.aspx).  If you're using the designer, check each column for an Auto-Sync property and set it to Never.

**Edit:**
Ok, that didn't work for you.  Brace yourself for some mapping hackery!

When I Insert with some autogenerated primary key column, I get this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName]( fieldlist )
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)

SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]
```

As I understand your request, you don't want that SELECT

Attempt 1: I went to the primary key field and set auto-generated to false.  This caused a Sql Exception "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TableName' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."   In other words, linq specified a value for that column.

Attempt 2: I deleted the autogenerated columns from the designer.  This caused Linq to give me an Invalid Operation Exception: "Can't perform Create, Update or Delete operations on 'Table(TableName)' because it has no primary key."

Attempt 3: I deleted the autogenerated columns from the designer, then I marked another column as primary key.  Even though this column is not a primary key in the database, LINQ's DataContext will use it to track row identity.  It must be unique for observed records of a given DataContext.

This third attempt generated the following SQL (which is what you ask for)

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName]( fieldlist )
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did that, but the profiler is still showing a select after both inserts and updates.  I don't know why.

Comment: I have two columns that are marked have AutoGeneratedValue set to true.  The select statement is selecting these two columns after inserts and updates, even though AutoSync is set to false.

Comment: That seems like a ludicrous amount of work to do for something that would have worked the right way the first time using ADO.Net

Comment: `then I marked another column as primary key` - how is this even possible as this column would be updated with the `unique value` by the SQL query which will most likely result in wrong data.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy "primary key" and "identity" are separate concepts and if you are tampering with an ORM's mappings it will help to know the difference between them.

Comment: I know the difference. Let me say it a different way: how do you ensure a `must be unique` without explicitly setting a unique value to a column that is not intended to hold this unique value?

Comment: @DavidB Thanks, the tracking info was missing.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy It doesn't need to be unique in the table. It only need to be unique from the point of view of the DataContext instance and then only if that context is tracking objects for changes. If you are inserting 1 record at a time, you have already won. If you are reading records sometimes, you can disable object tracking in those instances. If you are updating or deleting then it is much more difficult. (fixed grammar)

Answer (score 0):

I cant recall the setting now, but in the designer, on a column's properties, you have some 'refresh' setting(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a project once. I simply used the context.ExecuteCommand({sql string here.}). This was for one insert that was causing performance problems. Easiest fix, easy to see and maintain rather than digging through the model in my opinion.