# Linq To SQL, Do not SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() after INSERT

Tags: linq-to-sql

This is a follow up on the question [Stop LINQ to SQL from executing select statements after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407720/stop-linq-to-sql-from-executing-select-statements-after-insert) which somehow stayed unanswered.

I'm inserting 10,000 rows in a table, the primary key being auto-generated by SQL server. After inserting the rows, I do not need to post-process them, and the program is closed.

Looking at the LINQ to SQL log, for every INSERT, a consecutive SELECT statement for SCOPE_IDENDITY() is generated. I feel this is slowing down my program, and I would like to get rid of it.

How do I INSERT without the immediate SELECT ?

Comment: It may be worth benchmarking 10,000 `INSERT`s both with and without `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to see whether this really is slowing you down.  I've slapped a bounty on your original question as it is an interesting one.

Comment: I can't imagine that is adding any significant time (on a local/LAN server).

Comment: What would be the proper way to benchmark this? I just tried to INSERT 10,000 rows in my table using SQL Server Management Studio. It took 4:23" to INSERT without the SELECT, and 10:41" with the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about performance than I am afraid you have to change your approach completely.

Linq to Sql is not suitable for bulkinserts - as you have noticed it inserts them all one by one.

Since you are not post processing them you better use something like SqlBulkCopy. That is magnitudes faster.